# How to add a Blank UWP app as a reference of another Blank UWP app?

Tags: uwp

I want to add a Blank UWP app as a reference of another Blank UWP app. For example: I want UWP app "A" to be the reference of UWP app "B" but it returns these error codes when I build B:

Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'App.xbf'. Source files:
…\…\B\bin\…\…\App.xbf
…\…\A\bin\…\…\App.xbf

Comment: Can you explain why you're trying to do this? The error tells you what is wrong - both projects will generate files with the same names, so when you try to put them together in the same app they will conflict.

Comment: Possibly you have both project in same name so when you build both compile similar App.xaml.cs